# Is "myself" the grammatically correct choice?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I find it hard to explain to myself why "myself" is the grammatically correct choice in this sentence:

- When my friend came he joined **myself**, my wife, and my son at the table.

Often people write or say "**me**" instead, but I often see that in well-written books and in good-quality literature, "**myself**" is the more common choice. Does that mean that "**myself**" is the grammatically correct choice?

Comment: It's explained [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-myself-and-yourself) - better than I could explain it.

Comment: @BillyKerr, A side question. I see this from that link: *Staff who deal with the public in businesses such as restaurants*... , which I think it should be *Staff who **deals** with the public in businesses such as restaurants*... What do you think?

Comment: No. That is how we say it in the UK. There is no error. The word "staff" in that sense is plural here. Americans may disagree however.

Comment: "Staff" as a collective noun that can be either plural or singular, depending on context and local dialect was discussed in [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153117/can-i-use-few-with-staff/153144#153144).

Comment: The reflexive is not used  in that situation in standard AmE, although many people, trying to speak "correctly", will use it there, because they misremember or misunderstand what they were taught in school. It is a form of so-called "hypercorrectness"  *Myself* is certainly not the more common choice in AmE in non-reflexive contexts.  I don't think there's any AmE dialect correlation, but I do see a sociolect relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finding it hard to explain why it is correct because your use is disputed.

'Myself' is only universally accepted when 'I' am both the subject and the object of the verb. Thus:

> I hurt myself
>
> I made myself do it

If someone else is the subject then you would normally say

> He hurt me
>
> He made me do it

[This definition is given by Miriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myself)

Some authorities allow 'myself' to be used instead of 'me' in lists, in which case your construction is correct. [Cambridge Dictionary allows this.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/myself)

In any case **the version with 'me' is absolutely correct**.

> When my friend came he joined me, my wife, and my son at the table.

This construct occurs frequently in formal, correct writing.